# Issue with postbacks on asp.net pages viewed from mobile device

Tags: c#, asp.net, mobile, web, postback

I am facing an awkward problem. I am working on a .NET web site for which we are making a mobile version as well. The mobile version seems to be working fine when I am viewing it from the browser on my laptop, but when viewing it from a mobile device (in my case HTC running on Android), there is a problem on button clicks. The postbacks simply freeze the page and after some time `"Web page not available"` is displayed. Even for simple cancel buttons that only have `Response.Redirect` associated with them.

Has anyone witnessed similar situation? Any ideas on what can cause this? I am using .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 2):

The postbacks work through inserted JavaScript `(__doSubmit`). Mobile devices have patchy support for JavaScript. Is it possible to look at the device capabilities for instance by hooking into a [WURFL database](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) and look at the device capabilities. I could well imagine that this would be a problem for lower end devices but I am a bit surprised about HTC Andriod devices. Also to help isolate the issue I would test with a normal submit button i.e. one without `runat="server"` and see what happens then

Also you could try subverting your button and putting in some custom javascript to submit i.e.

```
OnClientClick="formname.submit();"
```

This [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1278187.aspx/1)  has some similar problems but with autosubmitting drop down lists

It's also dimly possible that the swollen `ViewState` is causing issues with the page size on postback. Generally if/when I have been developing for mobile I would turn this off if possible. The resulting page will be larger (a lot larger) than it needs to be. If nothing else you would need to make every effort to keep the pages as small as possible (IMHO)

I'm assuming that you are locked into webforms development at this point -so you could look at [ASP.Net mobile controls](http://www.asp.net/community/control-gallery/browse.aspx?category=48) to see if they behave better - there is a form control in there. But I have never used them or ever seen them used. Some other posters may have had great success with them though? Perhaps?

Not helpful but when we developed for mobile we used MVC which is at least more transparent in these kind of situations

Comment: hey Crab, thanks for the quick response. In the mean time, i asked couple of friends to check the site on their phones and guess what, everything seemed ok, one of which has same htc as i do. I tried to make clear data for my browser android app, but no luck with that. Anyway since the problem occurs on my phone only (for some reason), its not a big thing i guess. Will try it out from some other phones as well to make sure all is good. Thanks anyway for the other points you mentioned.

Comment: @stackjacksharper - no problems. One of those things perhaps